# What does pygame.sprite.Group() do

Tags: python, pygame

I am following a video about pygame and I saw this code

```
crosshair = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Could someone explain me this?

Comment: You could google it, SO is not the right forum for such questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).

[`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.
The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method.

> [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update)
>
> Calls the update() method on all Sprites in the Group.

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes

> [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw)
>
> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the Sprite.image attribute for the source surface, and Sprite.rect for the position.

The *Sprites* in the *Groups* can be removed and thus destroyed by calling [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite). When the object is no longer referenced, it is destroyed:

> The Sprite is removed from all the Groups that contain it. This won't change anything about the state of the Sprite. It is possible to continue to use the Sprite after this method has been called, including adding it to Groups.

See also [Sprite Groups](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md#sprite-groups)

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center_pos):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center_pos)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center_pos):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.image.fill((0, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center_pos)
    
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 10
        if self.rect.right > 300:
            self.kill()

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = Player((25, window.get_height() // 2))
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                all_sprites.add(Bullet(player.rect.center))

    all_sprites.update()
    print(len(all_sprites))

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (300, 0, 10, window.get_height()))
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```