# pygame "move_ip" method seems not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm doing a simple script, using pygame, that  simply moves a rectangle, but the method `move_ip` seems it is not doing anything (I followed the code found on a [RealPython tutorial](https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/) ).
In sum, I got a class `Player`, as follows:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self, pressed_k):
        if pressed_k[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_k[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_k[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_k[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)
```

Then I got an instance `player` of the class previously descripted, that is used in a loop, as follows:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)) 
    pygame.display.flip()
```

When I run the code it creates the windows properly (displaying a white rectangle, representing the player) and it seems that the program read the keyboard input but the block representing the player does not make any move.

(The instance method `.update` is called properly and also the various `'if'` statements work as they should but the relatives `self.rect.move_ip` don't make any change to the position of the player)

Comment: You don't use `player.rect` anywhere, try passing it to the call to `screen.blit`

Comment: ... `screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)`

Comment: Got it, now it works. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player is constantly drawn at `(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)`

> ```py
> screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
> ```

You have to drag the player to the position stored in the `rect` attribute. The 2nd argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) can be a rectangle. In this case the upper left corner of the rectangle will be used as the position for the blit:

```py
screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
```

---

However, if you are using [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) then you should also use [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).e.g.:

```py
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    player_group.update(pressed_keys)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    player_group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: What's the difference by using Group instance instead of Surface.blit ?

Comment: @Matt This cannot be answered with a single comment. See [What does pygame.sprite.Group() do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765971/what-does-pygame-sprite-group-do/68767767#68767767)  and the official documentation of the [`pygame.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module.