# how do i fix this pygame error AttributeError: 'Bullet' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

my code is copied below

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self ,x, y, direction):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 10
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.hitbox = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hitbox.center = (x,y)
        self.direction = direction


    def update(self):
        #move bullet
        self.hitbox.x +=(self.direction*self.speed)
        #check if bullet off screen
        if self.hitbox.right <0 or self.hitbox.left>SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.kill()
```

traceback:

> ```
>  File "C:\Users\bobby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 551, in draw
>    zip(sprites, surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites))        
>                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  File "C:\Users\bobby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 551, in <genexpr>
>    zip(sprites, surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites))        
>                                           ^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'Bullet' object has no attribute 'rect'
> ```

attempting to spawn in a bullet however the get_rect function from pygame to produce its hitbox is not working

Answer (score 1):

A `pygame.sprite.Sprite` object must have the attributes `image` and  `rect`. So rename `hitbox` to `rect`:

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self ,x, y, direction):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 10
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x,y)
        self.direction = direction

    def update(self):
        #move bullet
        self.rect.x +=(self.direction*self.speed)
        #check if bullet off screen
        if self.rect.right <0 or self.rect.left>SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.kill()
```

Also see [How can I add objects to a "pygame.sprite.Group()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924256/how-can-i-add-objects-to-a-pygame-sprite-group) and [What does pygame.sprite.Group() do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765971/what-does-pygame-sprite-group-do) or read the documentation of [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect` for the position.