# pygame flappy bird clone pipe-spawning

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm having trouble with spawning in the pipes from flappy bird, I'm trying to use a class for the information (surfaces, drawing rects, movement). However, I can't seem to figure out how to draw rectangles with it.

In my flappy bird clone, I'm using 2 pipes (one coming down from the top, and the other to the bottom). But what I've gathered so far is for drawing rects, you must use **self.rect**, which seems like it can only hold one value at a time, so I can't exactly access information for both the top and bottom pipes.

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # import files
        bird1 = pygame.image.load('graphics/bird/Bird1.png').convert_alpha()
        bird2 = pygame.image.load('graphics/bird/Bird2.png').convert_alpha()

        self.bird_fly = [bird1, bird2] # sets up animation index
        self.bird_index = 0
        self.gravity = 0

        self.image = self.bird_fly[self.bird_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (100,300))

    def animation(self):
        self.bird_index += 0.1
        if self.bird_index >= len(self.bird_fly): self.bird_index = 0
        self.image = self.bird_fly[int(self.bird_index)]

    def apply_gravity(self):
        self.rect.y += 5
    
    def input(self):   
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.rect.y -= 15


    def update(self): # gives access
        self.animation()
        self.apply_gravity()
        self.input()

class Pipes(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        top_pipe = pygame.image.load('graphics/pipes/top_green_pipe.png')
        bottom_pipe = pygame.image.load('graphics/pipes/bottom_green_pipe.png')


        pipes_list = [top_pipe, bottom_pipe]
        self.image = pipes_list[]
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (800, y))


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



pygame.display.set_caption('Flabby Pird')

#groups
player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player.add(Player())

pipes = pygame.sprite.Group()
pipes.add (Pipes())

#environment
sky = pygame.image.load('graphics/sky.png')
ground = pygame.image.load('graphics/ground.png')
fork = pygame.image.load('graphics/fork.png')
fork_rect = fork.get_rect(midbottom = (80, 200))


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.blit(ground, (0, 300))    
    screen.blit(sky, (0,0))
    screen.blit(fork, fork_rect)

    # draws player from "# groups"
    player.draw(screen)
    player.update() 

    screen.blit()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limits FPS to 60

pygame.quit()
```

here is my current code, im experimenting with drawing an entire list, but im not sure how to change the Y-value of each item in list

Comment: You have to create one Sprite form each pipe. There is no other possibilkity.

Answer (score 0):

A [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) represents one single sprite. Therefore you cannot handle multiple objects with one sprite. Create a pipe class and create 2 pipes. You can group the pipes together:

```py
class Pipe(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, is_top, image_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_name)
        if is_top:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (800, 0))
        else:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (800, 0))
```

```py
top_pipe = top_pipe(True, 'graphics/pipes/top_green_pipe.png')
bottom_pipe = bottom_pipe(False, 'graphics/pipes/bottom_green_pipe.png')
pipes = pygame.sprite.Group([top_pipe, bottom_pipe])
```

Also see [What does pygame.sprite.Group() do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765971/what-does-pygame-sprite-group-do/68767767#68767767)